# Eclipse exception during build

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I couldn't find a solution in other posts,

I have the following error in Eclipse when trying to build a project:
(Opens in a little pop-up window)

```
Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'C2S'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when looking in `<workspace_dir>\.metadata\.log` I see the stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2018-08-06 11:02:18.484
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 75 2018-08-06 11:02:18.484
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'C2S'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.internalAnalyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.analyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.internalAnalyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.analyseCode(TypeDeclaration.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Eclipse Version:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
```

Comment: what kind of build? maven, ant, default eclipse build?

Comment: @jhammon the "build" from Menu bar -> "Build project". My maven build works, surprisingly.

Comment: Which exact version of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin do you have?

Comment: @howlger I checked in "Eclipse installation details" - it's version `3.13.102.v20180330-0919`

Comment: If you can reproduce this issue with the current version of Eclipse (Photon; 4.8.0) without additional plugins, please report it to Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Core&version=4.8

Comment: Removed my eclipse (oxygen), and all files which could be related to it, even remotely. Installed eclipse photon - still happening. Maybe something is wrong wit my project?